# Is there a way in Linq to apply different calculations based on different conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to make it work.  Here's an example.  Could you correct it/translate it into linq syntax?

```
      From p In products() 
      group p by p.Category into g 
      select new { Category = g.Key, 
                   TotalUnitsInStock = if(g.key="b", g.Avg(p => p.UnitsInStock),
                                          g.Sum(p => p.UnitsInStock))
```

Products would be a datatable in this example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
  var query = from p In products() 
              group p by p.Category into g 
              select new { Category = g.Key, 
                  TotalUnitsInStock = (g.key=="b") ? g.Avg(p => p.UnitsInStock) :
                                      g.Sum(p => p.UnitsInStock));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from p in products()
group p by p.Category into g
select new
{
    Category = g.Key,
    TotalUnitsInStock = g.Key == "b"
        ? g.Average(p => p.UnitsInStock)
        : g.Sum(p => p.UnitsInStock)
}
```